# Check if there is a message received or skip it (python 3.4)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to ask how to skip the receive function.

```
def client():
    try:
        b = bytes.decode(h.recv(1024))
        print("The recieved message : ",b)
        b1 = str.encode(b)
        c.sendall(b1)
        h.sendall(b1)
        y.sendall(b1)
    except Exception:
        pass
    try:
        g = bytes.decode(y.recv(1024))
        print("The recieved message : ",g)
        g1 = str.encode(g)
        c.sendall(g1)
        h.sendall(g1)
        y.sendall(g1)
    except Exception:
        pass
```

So what I need to do is to check if there is a message coming from the client:

- If yes, print it and send it.
- if no, skip the function go to check with the other clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the polling mechanism. The simplest is [`select`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.select)

```
import select

def client():
    sockets, _, _ = select.select([h, y], [], [])
    # If h or y has data, select exits and returns these sockets

    for sock in sockets:
        try:
            data = sock.recv(1024)
            if data == '':
                # sock was disconnected handle that
                continue

            # Process data here
        except Exception:
            continue
```

Comment: still It is not receiving the message from the clients.

Comment: @user4823915: From code you posted (http://pastebin.com/PugZRPXn): you should call `select.select` _under_ the while loop. You're also call `sendall(g1)`, but `g1` is no longer defined, use data instead: `c.sendall(data)`

Comment: I tried that as well it is not working, I think it is not get the message because it can't print it.

Comment: @user4823915: I've fixed my answer, I forgot that select returns tuple of three lists :( Please do not silence exceptions in your code.

Comment: Thanks, It work now. If you just can explain what is going on ( why we use select and what is the purpose of it) to give better understanding

Comment: @MKM: [polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_%28computer_science%29) is a very common tecnique, I'm not sure that `select` can be explained without understanding of it. `select` is a way for poll multiple file descriptors if they become available.